# No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled

Tags: qt, qtwayland

I tried with the example modules given from Qt. and I downloaded the qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.3 tar file and extract it. 
then I run the following command.

> ./configure -v -prefix $PWD/qtbase -commercial -nomake tests -opengl
>   es2 -egl

but I got these errors.

> ```
> Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc
>
> Note: Dropped compiler flags '-pthread' when detecting library 'glib'.
>
> Note: Disabling X11 Accessibility Bridge: D-Bus or AT-SPI is missing.
>
> Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.
>
> ERROR: Feature 'egl' was enabled, but the pre-condition '(features.opengl || features.openvg) && (features.angle || libs.egl)' failed.
> ```

EGL related libraries installed on the system.

- Qt: 5.9.3
- Qt Creator: 4.4.1
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- GPU: Intel Haswell
- libva: 1.7.0
- VA-API: 0.39.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing some packages. If you want wayland, you're most likely going to need dev packages for `libwayland` and `libwayland-egl`, but I'm not sure what they're called on Ubuntu.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04: `sudo apt install libwayland-dev` should get you going.  It installs both libwayland and libwayland-egl see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwayland-dev)

That said, I think I still saw the "No wayland-egl support", but since I'm not cross compiling I think it's ok.